# Passing a String by Reference in Metro/C++?

Tags: string, reference, c++-cli, microsoft-metro

I'm working on a C++ Metro style app and have to pass a string by reference (somehow). At first, I passed the String^ which doesn't work because strings are immutable how I have found out.

What would be a proper way to pass a string by reference?

Edit: OK, it seems that it's not that easy since the answers and comments suggest to use return values. But as far as I think this is not applicable in my situation: In this Metro app I have two pages and a string should be "shared" across those two pages.
So in the main page I do this in a click event:
`this->Frame->Navigate(newPage, this->TestString);`

In the OnNavigatedTo event of the second page I convert the second parameter to a String^ and change it. Then I use `this->Frame->GoBack()` to navigate back to the first page. There I'd like to have access to the changed string. Unfortunately, GoBack() doesn't allow to pass any parameters as far as I know.

Comment: You really shouldn’t use pass by reference, use a return value as Botz said in his answer.

Comment: I updated my question to describe my situation with some more details. I'm afraid I don't know how to make use of return values in that situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a tracking reference:

```
void ModifyTheParameter(String^% value) {
    value = gcnew String("Blah");
}
```

That would modify the original variable you passed in as parameter ([see MSDN for more info and examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f63s5b1.aspx)). It would then be used just as any other method taking a `String^` parameter.

But if possible, avoid using tracking references as parameters. I'd recommend just returning a `String^` and assigning that to the original variable.

Yet another possibility: You could just create some kind of View-agnostic DataModel that contains your String (and possibly other data that you work with). You could then pass that DataModel to your method. Since the DataModel variable isn't changed (just a property of it), you wouldn't need to pass a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question so my situation is described with some more details. As you suggest I would avoid the tracking reference but I also don't see how to return a value in my situation.

Comment: @Sentropie I see. I added another possibility to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

See below an example of a function `f` which takes as a parameter a reference to a `std::string`.

```
std::string someString;

void f(std::string& s);

f(someString);
```